# Decimal to Double conversion in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, migration, type-conversion, swift3

I'm migrating a project from **Swift 2.2** to **Swift 3**, and I'm trying to get rid of old Cocoa data types when possible.

My problem is here: migrating `NSDecimalNumber` to `Decimal`.

I used to bridge `NSDecimalNumber` to `Double` both ways in **Swift 2.2**:

```
let double = 3.14
let decimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(value: double)

let doubleFromDecimal = decimalNumber.doubleValue
```

Now, switching to **Swift 3**:

```
let double = 3.14
let decimal = Decimal(double)

let doubleFromDecimal = ???
```

`decimal.doubleValue` does not exist, nor `Double(decimal)`, not even `decimal as Double`...
The only hack I come up with is:

```
let doubleFromDecimal = (decimal as NSDecimalNumber).doubleValue
```

But that would be completely stupid to try to get rid of `NSDecimalNumber`, and have to use it once in a while...

Well, either I missed something obvious, and I beg your pardon for wasting your time, or there's a loophole needed to be addressed, in my opinion...

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit** : Nothing more on the subject on **Swift 4**.

**Edit** : Nothing more on the subject on **Swift 5**.

Comment: yep, what a bummer still in 2018... the only reason I'm hesitating whether to move to Decimal is all the math operations (including literal conversions, like `myDecimal + 1`) and comparisons which are much more straightforward than with NSDecimalNumber

Answer (score 40):

`NSDecimalNumber` and `Decimal` are bridged

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the Decimal
>   structure, which bridges to the NSDecimalNumber class. The Decimal
>   value type offers the same functionality as the NSDecimalNumber
>   reference type, and the two can be used interchangeably in Swift code
>   that interacts with Objective-C APIs. This behavior is similar to how
>   Swift bridges standard string, numeric, and collection types to their
>   corresponding Foundation classes. [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimalnumber)

but as with some other bridged types certain elements are missing.

To regain the functionality you could write an extension:

```
extension Decimal {
    var doubleValue:Double {
        return NSDecimalNumber(decimal:self).doubleValue
    }
}

// implementation
let d = Decimal(floatLiteral: 10.65)
d.doubleValue
```

Comment: The question is still the same, even if it is hidden by an extension. You still have to use a third type instead of having only 'Double` and `Decimal`...

Comment: Voting for this to be the accepted answer in Swift 4. Clean, though not ideal solution, ideally the Decimal type should provide a double cast cleanly in the Swift language.

Answer (score 32):

Another solution that works in Swift 3 is to cast the `Decimal` to `NSNumber` and create the `Double` from that.

```
let someDouble = Double(someDecimal as NSNumber)
```

As of Swift 4.2 you need:

```
let someDouble = Double(truncating: someDecimal as NSNumber)
```

Comment: `let c = Double(truncating:a as NSNumber)` in Swift 4

Comment: @vikingosegundo That's Swift 4. In Swift 3 you don't need the `truncating`.

Comment: Yes but you still have to cast to a third type... You can't stay with only `Double` and `Decimal`, you need either to use `NSDecimalNumber` or `NSNumber`...

Comment: solution for 4.2 still works with Swift 5.8.2

Answer (score 16):

Solution that works in **Swift 4**

```
let double = 3.14
let decimal = Decimal(double)
let doubleFromDecimal = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: decimal).doubleValue
print(doubleFromDecimal)
```

Comment: Yes but you still have to cast to a third type... You can't stay with only `Double` and `Decimal`, you need either to use `NSDecimalNumber` or `NSNumber`... That's the point of this post...

Comment: @Zaphod Have you checked

Comment: Indeed it works... But you still use a third type, here `String` using the `description` property. The whole idea behind this post is the question of efficiency and clarity of the code. The point is that the type `Decimal` designed to replace good old `NSDecimalNumber` can't be used transparently without using a hack (via `NSNumber`, `NSDecimalNumber`, `String`, pointers, or something else...) The question is more rhetorical than about development... And the missing method, is still missing in Swift 4.

Comment: Don't ever rely on the .description property of any type. That's bound to go wrong at some point.

Answer (score 12):

#### Swift 5

```
let doubleValue = Double(truncating: decimalValue as NSNumber)
```

Comment: Indeed it works... But you still use a third type, here `NSNumber`. The whole idea behind this post is the question of efficiency and clarity of the code. The point is that the type `Decimal` designed to replace good old `NSDecimalNumber` can't be used transparently without using a hack (via `NSNumber`, `NSDecimalNumber`, `String`, pointers, or something else...) The question is more rhetorical than about development... And the missing method, is still missing in Swift 5.

Answer (score 3):

`Decimal` in Swift 3 is not [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimalnumber). It's [`NSDecimal`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimal?language=objc), completely different type.

You should just keep using `NSDecimalNumber` as you did before.

Comment: Actually, `Decimal` corresponds to `NSDecimalNumber`: `The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the Decimal structure, which bridges to the NSDecimalNumber class. The Decimal value type offers the same functionality as the NSDecimalNumber reference type, and the two can be used interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with Objective-C APIs` https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimalnumber

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov, except it has no methods of `NSDecimalNumber` available, so in order to use them you still gonna need to cast `Decimal` to `NSDecimalNumber`. Source: just checked it in playground.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't claim it did. I just said that your assumption that `Decimal` corresponds to `NSDecimal`, is wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov, but *it is* `NSDecimal`, just compare `Decimal` in generated headers of Swift 3 with `NSDecimal` in Foundation C code. Just because Swift **bridges** `Decimal` variable of old Foundation code to `NSDecimalNumber` when imported in doesn't mean `Decimal` becomes `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: Even though the documentation says that Decimal bridges to NSDecimalNumber, In my experience, it's safest to stick with NSDecimalNumber for now, and wait for the libraries to stabilize (tried converting over to Decimal, and it was messier than I expected, plus the resulting code crashed).

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to use `as` operator to cast a Swift type to its *bridged* underlying Objective-C type. So just use `as` like this.

```
let p = Decimal(1)
let q = (p as NSDecimalNumber).doubleValue
```

In Swift 4, `Decimal` *is* `NSDecimalNumber`. Here's citation from Apple's official documentation in Xcode 10.

> **Important**
>
> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the `Decimal`
>   structure, which bridges to the `NSDecimalNumber` class. For more
>   information about value types, see Working with Cocoa Frameworks in
>   Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 4.1).

There's no `NSDecimal` anymore.
There was confusing `NSDecimal` type in Swift 3, but it seems to be a bug.
No more confusion.

#### Note

I see the OP is not interested in Swift 4, but I added this answer because mentioning only about (outdated) Swift 3 made me confused.

Comment: What was meant here was not the underlying structure but a question of syntax. I know you have ti use the `as` operator to cast to a bridged type. My problem is just "what is the point to use `Decimal` instead of `NSDecimalNumber` if you still need to reference it once in a while?", for instance to get the double value... There is no way to change your code from `NSDecimalNumber` to `Decimal` transparently... That was just what I meant... And it is still the case in Swift 4 (as noted in the edit)

Comment: @Zaphod The point would be "using proper value type". You should know that many of `NS-` classes are actually designed to be value-types, but implemented in classes due to lack of language construct in OBJC. IMO, Apple want to provide more "Swift-y" library to Swift users, but their transition to Swift is not complete yet. There're many "incomplete" parts like this in Apple libraries, and they're likely to be updated later.

Comment: IMO, once after Apple successfully moved to Swift, they gonna remove access to OBJC part one by one.

Comment: That was exactly my point... The transition is not completely over with Decimal...

Comment: Bridging to a type isn't the same as being that type. `String` bridges to `NSString` and `Dictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary`, but they're entirely separate types. Further reading: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/working_with_foundation_types

Answer (score 3):

For swift 5, the function is

```
let doubleValue = Double(truncating: decimalValue as NSNumber)
```

the example in the below, show the number of float.

```
let decimalValue: Decimal = 3.14159
let doubleValue = Double(truncating: decimalValue as NSNumber)
print(String(format: "%.3f", doubleValue))  // 3.142
print(String(format: "%.4f", doubleValue)) // 3.1416
print(String(format: "%.5f", doubleValue)) // 3.14159
print(String(format: "%.6f", doubleValue)) // 3.141590
print(String(format: "%.7f", doubleValue)) // 3.1415900
```

Comment: Indeed it works... But you still use a third type, here `NSNumber`. The whole idea behind this post is the question of efficiency and clarity of the code. The point is that the type `Decimal` designed to replace good old `NSDecimalNumber` can't be used transparently without using a hack (via `NSNumber`, `NSDecimalNumber`, `String`, pointers, or something else...) The question is more rhetorical than about development... And the missing method, is still missing in Swift 5.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift open source, the [implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/cfac32b92d5fb62a651967cf22756352179b58ba/Sources/Foundation/Decimal.swift#L140) is actually done in `Decimal.swift`, but it is private. You can re-use the code from there.

```
extension Double {
    @inlinable init(_ other: Decimal) {
        if other._length == 0 {
            self.init(other._isNegative == 1 ? Double.nan : 0)
            return
        }

        var d: Double = 0.0
        for idx in (0..<min(other._length, 8)).reversed() {
            var m: Double
            switch idx {
            case 0: m = Double(other._mantissa.0)
                break
            case 1: m = Double(other._mantissa.1)
                break
            case 2: m = Double(other._mantissa.2)
                break
            case 3: m = Double(other._mantissa.3)
                break
            case 4: m = Double(other._mantissa.4)
                break
            case 5: m = Double(other._mantissa.5)
                break
            case 6: m = Double(other._mantissa.6)
                break
            case 7: m = Double(other._mantissa.7)
                break
            default: break
            }
            d = d * 65536 + m
        }

        if other._exponent < 0 {
            for _ in other._exponent..<0 {
                d /= 10.0
            }
        } else {
            for _ in 0..<other._exponent {
                d *= 10.0
            }
        }
        self.init(other._isNegative != 0 ? -d : d)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, but the real question remains, why `doubleValue` is declared as `internal` instead of `public` as it clearly should be... Maybe a pull request has to be done... But I don't know how to propose this... ‍♂️

Comment: You can create an evolution proposal on swift forums, and you'll get the feedback and reasoning behind the current implementation, and considerations regarding the proposal.

Comment: Yep, I'll add that to my todo list... 

Answer (score 0):

If you import Swift Charts, you can use `.primitivePlottable`

```swift
import Charts

let x: Decimal = 3.14159
let y: Double = x.primitivePlottable // 3.14159
```

But that's definitely not the intended way of doing it.

Comment: LOL! Excellent answer! Indeed that's not the intended way of doing it, but I like it!!!

Answer (score -3):

let decimalNumber = Decimal(10.5)
let doubleNumber = Double(decimalNumber)

print(doubleNumber) // Output: 10.5

Comment: This code doesn't compile. And please make some effort to format your answer correctly. Either indent the code 4 space or wrap the lines with three backticks (```)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it