# Decimal imported as NSDecimal not NSDecimalNumber in Swift 3 to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

I'm having problems with the type conversion between a Swift `Decimal` and an Objective C `NSDecimalNumber`.

If I have the Swift class:

```
@objc class Exam: NSObject {
    var grade: Decimal = 90.0
}
```

And try to use that Swift class in Objective C,

```
Exam *exam = [[Exam alloc] init];
NSDecimalNumber *result = [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalNumberByAdding:grade.value];
```

I get the error:

```
Sending 'NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSDecimalNumber * _Nonnull'
```

as it seems like `grade` is being treated as an `NSDecimal` not an `NSDecimalNumber`. This seems incorrect as per  it says

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the Decimal
>   structure, which bridges to the NSDecimalNumber class. The Decimal
>   value type offers the same functionality as the NSDecimalNumber
>   reference type, and the two can be used interchangeably in Swift code
>   that interacts with Objective-C APIs. This behavior is similar to how
>   Swift bridges standard string, numeric, and collection types to their
>   corresponding Foundation classes.

So I'm not sure if 1) I'm doing something wrong. 2) There's an error in the documentation or 3) This is a Swift bug.

I don't want to explicitly make the values in my Swift class `NSDecimalNumber` because then I cannot do simple arithmetic operations such as `+` without doing the whole ugly `decimalNumberByAdding` dance.

Comment: As far as I can see, `NSDecimalNumber` is the same in Objective-C and Swift, and `NSDecimal` in ObjC is `Decimal` in Swift. You can cast between them in Swift, but Swift does *not* automatically bridge between `NSDecimalNumber` in ObjC and `Decimal` in Swift (as it does for other overlay types). That might be a bug or an error in the documentation.

Comment: Similar confusion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890795/decimal-to-double-conversion-in-swift-3.

Comment: That documentation totally implies the behavior I'm expecting though, doesn't it? "The Decimal value type offers the same functionality as the NSDecimalNumber reference type, and the two can be used interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with Objective-C APIs". Probably going to bug report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the bridging feature of `Decimal` and `NSDecimalNumber` does not work like `String` and `NSString`, or `Array` and `NSArray`. But it's more like `Int` and `NSNumber`.

You would not expect `Int` properties in Swift can be accessible as `NSNumber` in Objective-C.

How about adding a getter for use with Objective-C:

```
extension Exam {
    @objc var gradeValue: NSDecimalNumber {
        return grade as NSDecimalNumber
    }
}
```

You can use it like this in Objective-C:

```
Exam *exam = [[Exam alloc] init];
NSDecimalNumber *result = [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalNumberByAdding:exam.gradeValue];
```